# Add related list after create a lookup field with metadata API

Tags: metadata-api, metadata, related-list

I would like to know if there's a way to add the related list in the parent object after I've created a lookup field trough the metadata-api?

this is what I'm doing:

1. Creating the field:

```
String relationshipObjectName = 'test'; 
MetadataService.MetadataPort service = new MetadataService.MetadataPort();
service.SessionHeader = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element(); 
service.SessionHeader.sessionId = UserInfo.getSessionId(); 
MetadataService.CustomField customField  = new MetadataService.CustomField(); 
customField.fullName = 'test'+;
customField.label= relationshipObjectName;
List results = service.createMetadata(new MetadataService.Metadata[] {customField}); 

result = handleSaveResults(results[0]);
```

After that I'm only updating the field level security with MetadataService.ProfileFieldLevelSecurity service..

Answer (score 1):

You can add related lists, but you have to do this "manually." The UI handles this for you by automatically giving you a choice as part of the field creation wizard, but if you're going about this programmatically, you need to actually query the page layouts (see [Layout](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_layouts.htm)), then add a new [RelatedListItem](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_layouts.htm#RelatedList) to the `relatedLists` part of the layout object(s). The actual process depends on what you're writing this in (I'm guessing Java or Apex Code, but it's not clearly specified/tagged here), but should basically consist of querying the layouts, constructing a new RelatedListItem, populating the various elements needed, then deploying the changes.